# How to obtain the opposite behaviour of vphantom to lift and align subscripts in LaTex

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have the following issue on the alignment of subscripts in LaTex. 
[image]

The line of code producing this, being

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}_{\Theta\Theta}\le\mathcal{T}_{\Theta \widehat\Theta}\le\mathcal{T}_{\Theta B}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I know that I can align the subscripts on the extrema with the one in the centre by using vphantom to lower them down, but I would like to obtain exactly the opposite. That is, raise the subscripts in the centre to obtain something like this
[image]

I couldn't find a way of doing this. Hope for your help.

Comment: With `\smash`? Try `\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}_{\Theta\Theta}\le\mathcal{T}_{\Theta \smash{\widehat\Theta}}\le\mathcal{T}_{\Theta B}
\end{equation}`